# Calling a PHP script on button press with Sencha Architect

Tags: html, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I've been looking at the documentation and tutorials for Sencha Architect, and I can't figure it out. What I want to is have a button press post a value to a PHP script on a server, and then retrieve the result from a PHP session variable. From what I've seen, I'm not sure if I can get it to call PHP at all, much less read a session variable.

I realize there may be a few questions in here (connecting the button to a controller/store, calling the script, reading the result), but I don't know enough about Architect to know if they're the correct ones.

EDIT: I think I've got the button connected to a controller, but I'm still not sure how to get it to call the PHP script.

EDIT 2:
I added a BasicFunction to the button, but I can't get it to work. Here's the code:

```
// Look up the items stack and get a reference to the first form it finds
var form = this.up('formpanel');
var values = form.getValues().getValues()[0];

Ext.Msg.alert('Working', 'Loading...', Ext.emptyfn);

Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'http://wereani.ml/shorten-app.php',
    method: 'POST',
    params: {
        url: values
    },
    success: function(response) {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Link Shortened', Ext.JSON.decode(response).toString(), function() {
            form.reset();
        });
    },
    failure: function(response) {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Error', Ext.JSON.decode(response).toString(), function() {
            form.reset();
        });
    }
});
```

Also, is that the correct way to get the value from the field (itemID:url)? I couldn't find anything in the documentation for Touch about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an Ext.Ajax request in the listener for the button. docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/?mobile=/api/Ext.Ajax.

The documentation there is pretty straightforward. If you have trouble please post some specifics and I'll try to write you an example.

Good luck, Brad

Comment: Ajax requests have to be on the same domain, it seems, but it doesn't say which domain that is. Does that mean that it needs to be a local request to the device and that i should use JsonP, or does it not matter?

Comment: Either use Chrome with security disabled for testing (stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/chrome-disable-same-origin-policy)  or use jsonp instead of json. You will not need to worry about cross origin policy when the app is running on a device. I would recommend using jsonp just because I don't and have several times wanted to demo a product for a client in a browser and not been able to because of the hoops needed to jump through to disable the same origin policy.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm not sure what I was doing wrong, but the JsonP request is working now except for a small bug in the PHP script I'm calling.